# Algorithm For Task

Tags: python, algorithm, analysis

i am trying to decrease the complexity of this loop, here is my code

```
def find_indexes(array, size, value):
    list_indexes = []
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if (array[i] + array[j] == value and i != j):
                list_indexes.append([i, j])
    return list_indexes

array = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
find_indexes(array, len(array), 12)
```

the output shows "[[0, 8], [1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1], [8, 0]]" which is corrent

but this solution has time complexity (N^2), can this be done in O(N) and O(NLgN)?
kindly propose an algorithm/code/psuedo-code for this.

the program basically compares each value with every other value sums the two values and compares with x. if it is equal to x. it appends it to a list.

the array is always sorted in descending order.
we have to find "[array[i] + array[j] == value, where i and j are two separate indexes of the array]"

Solution in O(N)

```
import math
array = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
size = len(array)
X = 12

def Q1_1_N(array, size, value):
    list_indexes = []

    i, j = 0, size - 1
    while (i <= j):
        j = size - 1
        while(j != int((size / 2) - 1)):
            if array[i] + array[j] == value:
                list_indexes.append([i, j])
            j -= 1
        i += 1

    return list_indexes


result = Q1_1_N(array, size, X)
print("Array :", array, "\nX :", X)
if result == []:
    print([-1, -1])
else:
    print("Result Indexes :", result)
```

Output :

Array : [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

X : 12

Result Indexes : [[0, 8], [1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5]]

Comment: it can be done in O(n) by hashing

Comment: is there any possibility of it without any such data structure? and if no then can you please propose the algorithm using hashing?

Comment: hashing in python is done with dictionary, which is built in

Comment: my bad, deleted the comment

Comment: @ChristianSloper yes but what do i assign as the key and values? and how do i traverse it to get the desired result?

Comment: It can be done in O(N) using two indexes. One index starts at the beginning of the array, and increases. The other index starts at the end of the array, and decreases.

Comment: @user3386109 yes, i updated the question with it, any algorithm for getting this done in O(nlogn) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **the array is always sorted** in descending order you can do this by scanning the array from both ends.  Something like this

```
p1 = 0
p2 = array.size -1
while p1 < p2
   let v = array[p1] + array[p2]
   while v < value
      if v = value then
          result.append(p1,p2)
          break -- exit the while loop
       p2--
       let v = array[p1] + array[p2]
   p1++
```

When the pointers meet your done as after that you'll just be generating mirror images of pairs you've already found.

If v becomes greater than value then there isn't a pair for the number pointed to by p1.

Comment: Thanks i managed to get the required O(N) complexity this way. any idea about O(NlogN)? ill update my solution with the O(N) one